# Mosaicking PDF documents?

Tags: image, pdf, thumbnails

I have (or, rather, will soon have) a number of maps created in ArcGIS 10.0 and exported as PDF documents. The maps all show contiguous areas, being rather like the pages in a map book. There will also be a smaller-scale map depicting the entire area (let's call it the "study area"), but with less detail, rather like that page of a map atlas that shows what page depicts what area.

I wonder if there is any way to create thumbnails of the larger-scale maps and mosaic them such as to create an index map of the study area. A user would then be able to see, for a particular point on the smaller-scale map, which of the larger-scale maps depicts that part of the study area. (And perhaps see that map by clicking on the larger map?) Does anyone have any ideas I can implement this? I would prefer exporting the maps in PDF format, but, if I can't do all of the above with PDF, then any other format to which a map can be exported from ArcGIS, such as JPG or TIF, will work.

Comment: I don't know ArcGIS but I assume that it creates PDF files using paths (vector graphics), not bitmaps. In that case I don't know how a tool should intelligently remove detail.  Inserting a smaller copy (with full detail), though, would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a PDF which does this.

What you need to do is render each page to a small image.

Then collect each of these images and add them as a mosaic to an index page.

Then put links from each small image back to the original PDF page.

If the hierarchy was more than one level deep you could repeat the process.

You need a PDF component to do this. What you want in terms of features is something which does decent PDF rendering. It's an easy thing to do badly and a difficult thing to do well.

ABCpdf .NET does good quality rendering so it's what I would suggest, but then I would because I work on it. :-)